# ZAP Attack proxy History Request ID is not consecutive

Tags: zap

I've used ZAP to intercept traffic .

Works nicely and I have a history  for my REQUEST - RESPONSE pairs like this:

```
ID      Req. TimeStamp                  Method     etc ..
...
1955    Tue Apr 05 15:42:47 CEST 2016   GET        https ://...
1971    Tue Apr 05 15:42:49 CEST 2016   GET        https ://...
1984    Tue Apr 05 15:43:30 CEST 2016   GET        https ://...
1998    Tue Apr 05 15:43:31 CEST 2016   GET        https ://... 
...
```

How come the IDs are not consecutive ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a FAQ for that :) https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/wiki/FAQhistoryIdsMissing

Simon (ZAP Project Lead)